# LWC handling search to unfilter

Tags: lightning-web-components, filters, lwc-wire-adapter, search

I am new to LWC development. I have a problem with handling search on a reverse. Meaning, handling backspace and delete made by the user. When the user types the product name, it will execute the search function. However, when they do the backspacing and altering their search value, the data from the data table is no longer exists. They will need to reload again. I was thinking of a clear button to resync. However, it will give additional steps to the user.

Here's my JS:

```
import { api, LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import fetchProducts from '@salesforce/apex/productPartnersView.fetchProducts';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Product Name', fieldName: 'NameURL', type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_blank'}
    },
    { label: 'Product Code', fieldName: 'ProductCode',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: { fieldName: 'icon' }, iconPosition: 'left' , 
        }
    },
    { label: 'Brand', fieldName: 'Brand', 
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: { fieldName: 'icon' }, iconPosition: 'left' , 
        }
    },
    { label: 'Product Family', fieldName: 'Family',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: { fieldName: 'icon' }, iconPosition: 'left' , 
        }
    },
    { label: 'Generic Name', fieldName: 'Generic',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: { fieldName: 'icon' }, iconPosition: 'left' , 
        }
    },
    { label: 'Barcode', fieldName: 'Barcode',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: { fieldName: 'icon' }, iconPosition: 'left' , 
        }
    }
];

export default class ProductPartnersView extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api title;
    @api showDetails;
    @api showsync;
    //@api recordId;
    @api usedInCommunity;  

    @track dataList;
    @track columnsList = columns;
    isLoading = false;

    connectedCallback() {
 
        this.handleSync();
    }

    getBaseUrl(){
        let baseUrl = 'https://'+location.host+'/';
        return baseUrl;
    }

    handleSync(){
        this.isLoading = true;
        fetchProducts()
        .then(result => {
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(result);
            let stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(parsedData);
            let finalData = JSON.parse(stringifiedData);
            let baseUrl = this.getBaseUrl();
            finalData.forEach(dataRec => {
                dataRec.Name = dataRec.Name;
                dataRec.NameURL = baseUrl + 'lightning/r/Product2/' + dataRec.Id + '/view';
                dataRec.ProductCode = dataRec.ProductCode;
                dataRec.Brand = dataRec.Brand_Name__c;
                dataRec.Family = dataRec.Family;
                dataRec.Generic = dataRec.Generic_Name__c;
                dataRec.Barcode = dataRec.StockKeepingUnit;
            });
            
            this.dataList = finalData;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('**** error **** \n ',error)
        })
        .finally(()=>{
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }

    handleSearch(event){
        
        let name  = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        if( name === 'Name' ){
            this.dataList = this.dataList.filter( dataRec => {
                return dataRec.Name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
            });
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, when you are retriving the data in `handleSync` you can add the data into two attributes. For example:

```
this.dataList = finalData;
this.databackupList = finalData; //to save the backup of data you are retriving using handleSync function
```

and then you can filter using `this.databackupList`. For example:

```
this.dataList = this.databackupList.filter( dataRec => {
                return dataRec.Name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
            });
```

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you! :)